# Chrome didn't response correctly with AutoHotKey sequence Alt, Space, N

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, autohotkey

I wrote a script with AutoHotkey to minimize a current using windows task. Namely a sequence of key of Alt, Space, n activated by the press of the right Win key.

```
RWin::Send !{Space}n
```

It work perfectly with every software including Firefox but failed in Google Chrome. It just open the File menu and does nothing.

I also tried the following but it made things worse, all the software don't response correctly.

```
RWin::Send !{Space}
      Sleep, 100
      Send n
      return
```

Comment: Does the key combination work when done manually? It works for me in Chrome under Windows 7, XP may be different for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes, it works when done manually. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`WinMinimize, A`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm) command to minimise the active window:

```
RWin::WinMinimize, A
```

It's probably better than a sequence of keypresses that activate a context menu option. It apparently sends the same minimise [message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) as the option on that context menu, or the minimise button (top right corner): [`SC_MINIMIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Tested to work on `Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m`, Windows 7 x64, `AHK 1.0.48.05`.

Answer (score 0):

Make it:

```
RWin::Send {Alt}{Space}n
```

Tested and working with latest chrome on Windows 7 x64

Comment: Thing is, I tested his `!{Space}n`, which also works for me on Win7x64. Unless someone else can confirm this for XP, that slight difference in command *probably* won't help (who knows, this might actually work - it might be an odd bug).

Comment: Bob, I too tested !{Space}n. It works for all programs except chrome(I don't know why..)

Comment: Ok, that is odd. I'm running `Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m`, `AHK 1.0.48.05`. Perhaps a version specific issue. Or just something entirely random.

Comment: You may have to run an AHK script with Administrator privileges to override any keyboard hooks a program may be using. For example, Notepad++ is stubborn this way due to its macro features.

Comment: @iglvzx Chrome shouldn't be hooking the right Windows key. In fact, most programs shouldn't. Unless he has a plugin installed? (hint to OP: try disabling plugins to test)